# How to change the X axis data type in C# asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph, windows-forms-designer

I have populated data from data from SQL server 2014 to Visual Studio 2013.

When I have a date value its shows in numbers not in date format for X-axis.

Please help to change it to date value

[image]

Comment: have you set the data type in the graph?? Can you show your code?

Comment: fillChart(Chart ch, string query, string x1, string y1, string series1,string legend, string x2, string y2, string series2,string legend2)
        {
            DBCon db = new DBCon();
            ch.DataSource = db.GetDataSet(query).Tables[0];
            ch.Series[series1].XValueMember = x1;
            ch.Series[series1].YValueMembers = y1;
            ch.Series[series1].LegendText = legend;
            ch.Series[series2].XValueMember = x2;
            ch.Series[series2].YValueMembers = y2;
            ch.Series[series2].LegendText = legend2;
            ch.DataBind();
       }

Comment: I haven't set a data type in this method